# Relationship between textLabel and contentView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Would it make sense to use both `textLabel` and `contentView` in a `UITableViewCell` or does one "cover" the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of `UILabel` is created and added to the content view the first time you access the `textLabel` property. Generally, you're either going to customize the content view by adding subviews yourself, or else use the built-in `textLabel` (and optionally, `detailTextLabel`) property.